# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory- vs code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

I have completely followed [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for the **react-native project**, now when I am running the first app from Andriod studio **run BUTTON** it installs and runs perfectly. The problem comes when I run the command  `yarn react-native run-android` it throws the following error:

---

info JS server already running

info Installing the app...

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin;
```

Please set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

```
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this co
```

---

[snapshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dydbG.png)

**My jdk path:**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin;

## My question is:

If the jdk path is invalid then why it is running in android studio?

Comment: _"If the jdk path is invalid then why it is running in android studio?"_ My first guess would be that Android Studio is using its own bundled JDK.

Comment: hi Michael! can you please guide me on how I check and if it is using its own bundle how could I set my own to either as code or both, as for environment variables I set JAVA_HOME already as mentioned above,

Comment: I had the same issue while setting up for react native, set up java home to the proper directory, and then check in the terminal if `java` command and `javac` command works. If both works then shutdown the system after closing all programs and then start it over.

Comment: JAVA_HOME should be a single directory. In your case, it should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or VS Code??

Answer (score 3):

You should edit your path as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1" bin is not required.

To set JAVA_HOME
1-Search for Environment Variables 
2-Under system variables click new 
3-In the variable name enter JAVA_HOME, in the variable value enter the JDK path  
which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"

Answer (score 2):

It seems the terminal caches the earlier environment variables.
Before moving ahead make sure you have already changed the correct path for JAVA_HOME.

Now, Open Visual code and close the terminal, and reopen it (ctrl + ~)
error should be gone

Comment: Thanks. Just some additional info, it needs close the terminal using the Kill Terminal (Bin icon) and then restart VS Code.

Comment: yes ! you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in flutter. I deleted the "JAVA_HOME" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" value that I wrote earlier in the system variables section under the environment variables menu. I ran the terminal again and ran "flutter doctor --android-licenses" in the terminal. Problem solved.
[image]